# How can I use custom ngTemplate

Tags: angular

I want to create small component with one custom / optional template - it would be nice if I can made it similar to Kendo

```
<kendo-combobox>
    <ng-template kendoComboBoxFooterTemplate>
        <h4>{{listItems.length}} sizes available</h4>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-combobox>
```

so if that template is defined inside body then I'll use it, if don't I'll use default one.

I'm trying to play with ngTemplateOutlet but right now with maybe half od desired solution is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `@ContentChild()` to get your component body content,try this

```
import { ContentChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class YourComponent {
 @ContentChild(TemplateRef) contentChild: TemplateRef<any>;
```

and in your template you can check `contentChild` property, if it isn't `undefined` then your component has body